# how can I make a list of callable commands python?

Tags: python, command, python-3.x

I was wondering how you go about making a list of commands the user can enter. Like for example, user types in "who" to get a list of who is on in a MUD.  Is it all done using if, elif and else in pythons?

I am using Python 3.1 btw.

Answer (score 11):

Nope. Dispatch dictionary.

```
def who(*args, **kwargs):
   ...

commands = {
  'who': who,
   ...
}

...
if command in commands:
  commands[command](*args, **kwargs)
else:
  print('Bad command or file name')
```

Comment: note that the user commands do not need to match the function name, and that is a good way to give different players opaque access to different command sets. At the same time, as the coder you will be able to differentiate wizard_say() from player_say(). 

I mean to say that each account would have its own commands dictionary.

Answer (score 4):

The [`cmd`](http://docs.python.org/library/cmd.html#module-cmd) module is made for this. Just subclass `cmd.Cmd()`, including a set of methods that begin `do_XXX` - so `do_who()` would provide the `who` command.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the `input` function to get command-line input from the user:

> input([prompt])
>
> If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output
>   without a trailing newline. The
>   function then reads a line from input,
>   converts it to a string (stripping a
>   trailing newline), and returns that.

Here's a small example:

```
s = input("Enter a command: ")
if s == 'who':
  # do stuff
elif s == 'help':
  # show help
else
  # do other stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

You are able to import the sys module and than use the sys.stdin.readline() part of that module. That will accept input from a command line or terminal, which means you have to run it from one of those too.

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write("$ ")
command = sys.stdin.readline()
command = command.strip() #Remove the new line character
if command = argument:
    do code
elif command = other argument:
    do more code
else:
    Thats not a command than
```

The benefits of using this is that, under a linux system, the program is still able to run. For example, I use it to accept commands to check on my server/client program to find the sum of 3 cubes. I can tell it to quit, check the found cubes, or look at the list of clients and threads.

Comment: I've never seen `sys.stdin` used like this - and it gives me a `TypeError` - are you sure you have it working?

Comment: I just tested it myself, it works because of the module I use to accept connection requests which has built in support for this. There may be a module like it for general use, but otherwise disregard my answer.

Comment: However, I just thought of another part of the sys function, editing my post now.